# WCF Rest Datamember and Array issue

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, rest, datamember

I've created a WCF service and the service is receiving the XML structure with all the data but the PackageID and ServiceCode.  The problem seems to be in public RequestPackages[] Packages in the Track class.

If I change it to RequestPackages in the code below then the element data will be passed into the service method and will show in the PackageID/ServiceCode elements.

If I have it as RequestPackages[]  then I get this stepping through in debug in the xml for Packages Element: wcf.RequestPackages[0] and PackageID/ServiceCode are not available.  I am stepping through debug to view xml data passed as it hits the service method. I'm not sure how to resolve it but I've probably overlooked something simple.  Thanks

Below is the Xml structure being sent:

```
<Track>
  <Packages>
    <PackageId>1234567890</PackageId>
    <ServiceCode>123</ServiceCode>
  </Packages>
</Track>
```

Below is the Data contracts:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
[XmlArrayItemAttribute("Package")]
public partial class Track
{

    private RequestPackages[] packagesField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [DataMember(Order=0, Name="Package")]
    public RequestPackages[] Packages
    {
        get
        {
            return this.packagesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.packagesField = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public partial class RequestPackages
{
    private string packageIdField;
    private string serviceCodeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    [XmlElementAttribute]
    public string PackageId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.packageIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.packageIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [DataMember(Order=1)]
    [XmlElementAttribute]
    public string ServiceCode
    {
        get
        {
            return this.serviceCodeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.serviceCodeField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the issue.   I was missing an element in the xml... <RequestPackages>
     
    <Packages>
      <RequestPackages>
         <PackageId>1234567890</PackageId>
         <ServiceCode></ServiceCode>
      </RequestPackages>
    </Packages>

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an element in the xml...

```
<Packages>
  <RequestPackages>
     <PackageId>1234567890</PackageId>
     <ServiceCode></ServiceCode>
  </RequestPackages>
</Packages>
```